# Creating a dynamic call_user_func_array

Tags: php

I am trying to create a dynamic search query based on which fields are clicked, mostly check boxes, on a search form.  The form has up to 10 search fields.  The below script works perfectly IF the user clicks exactly 3 specific fields.  IF the user clicks anything other than 3, it doesnt work.  I get that it is based on the $param array, but how do I make it dynamic if the user picks a different number of search fields.  It might not be pretty, but what I have works.  Sorry, still learning.

```
    //  Validating and filtering already done.


// Populate for testing purposes.  .  Assign variables from the search form
$formdata01 = 5;
$formdata02 = 1;
$formdata03 = 1;
...


$mybinder01 = 'i';
$mybinder02 = 'i';
$mybinder03 = 'i';
...


// Cols to display
$tablecols = 'tblcol01, tblcol02, tblcol04, tblcol05, tblcol06, tblcol07, tblcol08, tblcol09, tblcol10 ';


// Placeholders
$myholder01 = 'tblcol04 = ?';
$myholder02 = ' AND tblcol05 = ?';
$myholder03 = ' AND tblcol06 = ?';
...


// combine the placeholders together
$myholder99 = $myholder01.$myholder02.$myholder03;


// Combine the bind parameters
$mybinder99 = $mybinder01.$mybinder02.$mybinder01;


// The sql query
$mysql = "SELECT $tablecols FROM userdata WHERE $myholder99";
echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';


// Prepare the query
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare( $mysql );


// Create the bind parameters
$param = array($mybinder99, &$formdata01, &$formdata02, &$formdata02);


call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $param);


$stmt->execute();

// Execute it
$stmt->execute();

// Get results
$result = $stmt->get_result();

// Get number of rows returned
$returned = $result->num_rows;

// Check if returned is greater than 0
if ( $returned > 0 )
{
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
    {
        $test_col01 = $row['tblcol01'];
        $test_col02 = $row['tblcol02'];
        $test_col03 = $row['tblcol04'];
        $test_col04 = $row['tblcol05'];
        $test_col05 = $row['tblcol06'];
        $test_col06 = $row['tblcol07'];

        echo 'FOUND col01 data is: '. $test_col01;
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'FOUND col02 data is: '. $test_col02;
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'FOUND col04 data is: '. $test_col04;
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'FOUND col05 data is: '. $test_col05;
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'FOUND col06 data is: '. $test_col06;
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'FOUND col07 data is: '. $test_col07;
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'NO Records were found.';
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Hi you need to create dynamic bind array see below

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it done you just need to create bind array dynamically.
ie this part

```
// Create the bind parameters
$param = array($mybinder99, &$formdata01, &$formdata02, &$formdata02);
```

But since you told you are beginner let me explain with an example

Suppose I have 5 textboxes , 1st 4 of them for numeric and last one for string input which corresponds with the matchig datatype in the table

```
<input type="text" name="tblcol01">
<input type="text" name="tblcol02">
<input type="text" name="tblcol03">
<input type="text" name="tblcol04">
<input type="text" name="tblcol05">
```

Sometimes user may provide value for only one field other times he may provide for a few others so we don't know beforehand how many fields we need to bind that why we use `call_user_func_array()` that part you 
got correctly

Now the next part is look in `$_POST` and decide what fields user provided and we need to bind.

```
// ************ connect ***********//
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
$last_error = '';
if($mysqli->connect_error) {
  $last_error = 'Cannot connect to database. ' . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
echo $last_error;
// ************ connect ***********//

$mybinder99 = ''; // will be like 'iiiis'
$formdata99 = array(); 

$allPossibleFields      = array('tblcol01','tblcol02','tblcol03','tblcol04','tblcol05');
$fieldsDatatypes        = array('i','i','i','i','s');


foreach($allPossibleFields as $k=>$value)
{
    if(!empty($_POST[$value]))
    {
        $myholder99[] = $value;          // name  of field
        $formdata99[] = &$_POST[$value]; // value of field
        $mybinder99 .= $fieldsDatatypes[$k]; //datatype of field
    }
}

$myholder99 = implode('  = ? AND ' , $myholder99);
$myholder99 .=  ' = ? ';
// will give you something like tblcol01 = ? AND tblcol05 = ?  ... AND tblcol0n = ?

$mysql = "SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE $myholder99";
$param = array_merge( array($mybinder99) ,  $formdata99);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare( $mysql );
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $param);

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

echo '<pre>';

while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first of all, thank you so much.  It works and is great.  A few things I have noticed and not quite sure how to modify.

1. The $_Post field name has to match the database/table column name.  I thought it was good security if the column names are not known.  I am not that savvy, so I could very well be wrong.
2. I see where the &$_POST[$value] is used.  Now again, being a beginner, I typically put all my $_Post data straight to a variable.  Maybe my inexperience or stubbornness, but I put the information to variables to keep the original $_Post untouched and filter and etc the variables.  By the looks of it, I can not do that.
3. The variables $allPossibleFields ( array ) and $fieldsDatatypes ( array ) have to be built manually.  As an example, I tried adding the possible field types together into 1 variable and inserted that in lieu of the ('1','1','1') part and that crapped out.

Am I crazy?  Too picky?  I just want a form and based on what the user clicks as search fields to then populate into strings and run that against my database/table.